# Flutter dotenv package how to import environment variables into Travis that is in .env file that is in gitignore

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables

This is .env file, it's in gitignore.
CLIENTID=Some_value

In main() I am loading that file and read later in project, but how to import .env file into travis, but without showing value in git repo directly.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

Comment: But if I am loading from DotEnv().load('.env'); how to override values with environment that is set at travis? should it be with CLIENTID=$CLIENTID and than set to env:
  - CLIENTID=someOthervalue